# "Неожиданно" в непривычном употреблении, - чем заменить?

Tags: выбор-слов

"Неожиданно" в смысле "не ожидаешь обнаружить себя на..."

> Даже после трёхчасового перелёта неожиданно оказаться на равнине.

Comment: А зачем менять - и так хорошо.

Comment: Может быть Вы хотели бы добавить деталь в отношении рассказчика к описываемому событию?
Напр., "Даже после трёхчасового перелёта [нам казалось странным] неожиданно (вдруг, как по мановению волшебной палочки и т.д.) оказаться на равнине."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В качестве варианта:** Даже после трёхчасового перелёта **вдруг разом**  оказаться на равнине.

Пример: Печора делает крутой поворот и из-за длинной песчаной косы **вдруг разом** возникает селение:  [Василий Голованов. Остров, или оправдание бессмысленных путешествий (2002)]

Answer (score 2):

Можно заменить на "вдруг".

А что Вас смутило? Зачем менять? Синонимов у "неожиданно" много: нежданно, нежданно-негаданно, внезапно, каким-то чудом - и все в этом смысле.

Comment: Нам "даже" мешает использовать синоним; так-то и без синонима хорошо. Вместо наречия, заменяющего глагол, мне нужен сам глагол!

Comment: А вон в чём дело, а я не пойму никак. Может, так: Даже после трёхчасового перелёта   бывает неожиданным  оказаться на равнине.

Comment: Или: никак не ждёшь.Или :  Теряешься от неожиданности оказаться.